# Can you use AWS Fargate to run untrusted code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

I'm looking to add code execution to a SaaS platform.

I've review several options (e.g. OpenFaas, OpenWhisk, AWS Firecracker, gVisor)...
Seems like each has their own hurdles to implement.

Is there any reason not to use AWS Fargate to run customer's untrusted code?

Comment: Biggest reason: It's untrusted code.

Comment: True, however AWS can't trust everyone with an AWS account to run safe code... including you and me ;)

Comment: What do you mean by untrusted code?

Comment: @RodrigoM, SaaS will allow customer to store and run code on the platform.

Comment: Yes, you can run untrusted code within Fargate. The only things you should make absolutely sure are that it cannot communicate with anything else in the VPC, does not have internet connectivity and probably should not have *any* IAM permissions.

Comment: AWS virtualizes the code run, it cannot escape its virtualization / its account. *If* it can escape it that is big security flaw on AWS' side and a risk that they are always aware of: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/130274/how-do-big-cloud-providers-guard-against-vm-escape-attacks .

Comment: Thanks @luk2302. My understanding is that AWS uses Firecracker for this... so by using Fargate, you're basically using Firecracker as a managed service.

Comment: Curious --- did you end up implementing this on Fargate?  And, if so, any tips?

Comment: I didn't but I do use Fargate a lot! Think the answer is yes, but risky because you're liable if code goes malicious.